# Is there any resource leak if I use streaming with BufferedReader in Java

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, bufferedreader

This is pretty much code I have. (no `read` or `close` calls). Do I need to close either InputStream or BufferedReader? is there any code smell/ resource leak here?

```
InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
String response = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream)).lines()
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

**EDIT**

based on answer, is this correct

```
InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
String response;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream))) {
                    response = br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
                }
```

Comment: In Java 7 or newer use try to automatically close Closables. It will save you hair tearing at some point in the future.

Comment: yes, sir. I know autoclosables. but do I need one here in the context of streaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the stream is not auto closed on performing the stream pipeline operation in such cases and in fact as stated in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) there are also *no guarantees that the reader will be at a specific position from which to read the next character or line.*

In short `Stream`s ([java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream)) are not responsible for manipulating the stream ([stream](/questions/tagged/stream)) that has been passed on for processing as a resource. Hence the preferred way to ensure auto-closable streams in such a case would be using *try-with-resource* approach as follows :

```
try (InputStream stream = request.getEntity().getContent();
     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))) {
    String response = bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

Comment: how about my edit based on your suggestion, since I will be using `response` outside of try block.

Comment: @brainstorm you can initialize `response` before the `try{}` block if that is what you meant. there is no resource leak in terms of that variable assignment. on the contrary, did you explicitly wanted to keep the `InputStream` outside of the try as well? not sure of other usages, but you could have also just used `try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getEntity().getContent())))...` and used the reader to find the `response`.